# calling Log Off method using Ajax.beginform

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an asp mvc 5 website. I have used identity 2 for user accounts. I have changed my layout thus i changed the default behaviour of views. now i saw this partial view in my project.

```
 @using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
    }
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

I read somewhere that using javascript to submit a log off form will be a bad idea if the user has disables javascript. So my question is can i use ajax to submit this form? they used javascript because the page will not be gets loaded again for postback. if i use simple button to submit the page gets posted back. so is there any alternate way than this javascript submit?

Comment: Ajax _is_ javascript.  It stands for "asynchronous JavaScript and XML".

Comment: Why would the _page gets posted back_?  You should be redirecting back to your home page (or another page) in the POST method if the logout is successful. And if javascript is disabled, then you ajax will not work